# how to include css inside javascript code in codeigniter view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, printing

I want to include the css files inside the javascript  tags using base_url(). I want to print a specific div using the javascript in codeigniter view with css.

my script part:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />

<div class="panel panel-primary"  id="printableArea">
    I want to print this content here.
</div>
```

i want to print the text only inside the div when i click the button.can anyone help??

Comment: can you explain the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific CSS for print alone you should directly include in the codeigniter view page and give the media type as print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```